# "em" based css for non-proportional width and height

Tags: css

When working with multiple resolutions, the "em" based approach seems a good way to code your css file. However, if you have say two resolutions 480x800 & 540x960, then the width ratio ( 540/480 = 112.5% ) is NOT same as height ratio ( 960/800 = 120% ).

So, if I have an em font size = 112.5% for moving from lower resolution to higher, the width seems perfectly aligned to new resolution but height ( which expects font-size of 120% ) seems to fall short and therefore there is a white blank space created at the bottom after rendering all elements for the page.

Any solution to this problem would be great help.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are hoping to accomplish. You want to fill the screen with text, no matter what the resolution?

Comment: No , that's not what i want to accomplish . Just need one answer in short . For non-proportional resolutions ( like 480x800 & 540x960 ) how do you manage em for width and height for entire screen occupancy.

Comment: What are you appying the size of 112.5% to? You talked about `em` - which is a dimension relative to the current font size (e.g. if the font size is 10px then `1.5em` = 15px) - but then quote percentages, which is confusing. Could you elaborate on what you're asking and maybe provide some example code?

Comment: You don't want to use ems if you are trying to match screen size. There is no way to do that. Ems are great for many things, but you have to stick to % if you are concerned about occupying certain amounts of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

`em` is a unit of choice for *fonts*, not so much for element dimensions. With it evaluating to element's `font-size`, it's simply not reasonable to be setting widths using this unit.

You may be trying to refer to [a vertical rhythm](http://24ways.org/2006/compose-to-a-vertical-rhythm), which is a concept of maintaining text readability and should *not* be confused with the rest of the page layout.

For aesthetically pleasing rendering under different resolutions, you should look into [fluid layouts](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/09/smart-fixes-for-fluid-layouts/) - try playing with the browser width on that page. As you can see, the content flow is altered to make best use of space available, however the font size/line-height are not adjusted since the two techniques are independently implemented.